# Django REST framework - HyperlinkedRelatedField with additional parameter

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm building REST Web API with Django Rest framework.
I have a many-to-many relation between categories and wallets.
Starting from a category I retrieve all wallets its linked to, and from the shell everything works fine

Models:

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    creato = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    utente = models.ForeignKey(User)
    wallettype = models.ForeignKey(Wallettype)
    payway = models.ManyToManyField(Payway, through = 'Wpw', blank = True)
    defaultpayway = models.ForeignKey('Wpw', related_name = 'def_pw', null = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome

class Category(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    creato = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    enus = models.ForeignKey(Enus)
    wallet = models.ManyToManyField(Wallet)
    utente = models.ForeignKey(User)
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='owner_cat')
```

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.cat_list.as_view()),
    url(r'^/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/*$', views.cat_detail.as_view()),
    url(r'^/(?P<cat_id>[0-9]+)/wallets/*$', views.cwallet_list.as_view()),
    url(r'^/(?P<cat_id>[0-9]+)/wallets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/*$', views.cwallet_detail.as_view(), name='cwallet-detail'),
)
```

Serializer:

```
class cat_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    wallet = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='cwallet-detail',
        # lookup_field = 'pk',
        # lookup_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    )
    subcat_count = serializers.IntegerField(
        source='subcategory_set.count',
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'nome','wallet','subcat_count')
```

When I call:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/categories/77/wallets
```

I would like to retrieve:

```
{
    'nome': 'Dinner',
    'subcat_count': 12,
    'wallet': {
        'http://localhost:8000/77/wallet/1',
        'http://localhost:8000/77/wallet/2',
        'http://localhost:8000/77/wallet/3',
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work and I get this error:
*"Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "cwallet-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field."*

I think that the problem is linked to the additional param: in fact in my urls.py I have pk for the wallet id and cat_id for the category id.
I can't figure how to pass the category id to the 'cwallet-detail'.

Anyone know how to pass a second paramater to the HyperlinkedRelatedField?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After reading docs and posting a [new issue](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3204) on [Tom Christie's Django REST github](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework), now I know that it's not officially supported, but doumentations and patch are work in progress.

Actually there is **[this link](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/commit/472784b70aeec2e2afce5c39757d6140533ab32e)** for building a *Custom Hyperlinked Filed* to solve the problem.

Hope this help someone who has same problem.