# REST Web API - many-to-many relationship

Tags: api, rest

Ok, my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718385/django-rest-framework-hyperlinkedrelatedfield-with-additional-parameter) had no answers, so I've the doubt that I'm walking on the wrong way.

I'm developing some Web REST Api for a mobile application, and regarding *REST best pratices* I don't know how to face a many-to-many relationship.

**I have two tables, Wallets and Cateories, between these tables there is a many to many relationship since a category may be associated to different wallets and a wallet may own different categories.**

Actually this database is used by a non rest website:
*when a user creates a new category, he choose from the list of his own wallets which wallets to connect it to, and with this single POST call the category is created and conneted to the wallets.*

I don't think that replicating this behaviour is compliant to REST best pratices.

My first idea was to "expose" the connection between categories and wallets with this form:

`http://localhost:8000/categories/77/wallets/4`

but I had the problem I wrote on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718385/django-rest-framework-hyperlinkedrelatedfield-with-additional-parameter), and I don't think this is the right way.

Anyone has a valid method to manage a many-to-many realtionship according with *REST best pratices*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/categories/77/wallets/4` looks just fine

Comment: @Tim: so the sequence is (1) ask for the list of user wallets (2) individually create the *connection* between the category and selected wallet?

Answer (score 0):

Namespacing wallets by a category is fine, as in /categories/77/wallets/4. You can also consider a more concise scheme like /categories/77/4 or /wallets/77/4 if there are only wallets in a category.

However, you don't have to namespace. Your wallets presumably have their own IDs, so you could also just expose them as /wallets/4.

Is it worth the effort? I think it can be a good practice if your URLs are also on a public website (in which case you would probably want to support slug IDs as well, e.g. /categories/luxury/wallets/acme). If not, you should be aware it will be a little more configuration work on the server-side and a little more work for clients (clients will have to be aware of 2 IDs instead of 1).

Comment: In a category there are subcategories too, so I think I can't do something like categories/77/4.  
  
My `wallets`, sure, have their own ID, I can't figure out how to use simply /wallets/4 in order to add a "connection" between categories and wallet. I think I will always have tu pass the category ID, isn't it?

Comment: Simple, just pass the category ID in the request body, just like you'd pass any other data. You probably have other associations to setup too, so there doesn't have to be anything special about the wallet's category. The server will then perform the usual validations about whether the category exists and if it will allow the wallet.